# Special characters in mysql sqoop import as Text and Parquet file

Tags: mysql, hive, special-characters, sqoop, parquet

I have 1000 tables with more than 100000 records in each table in mysql. The tables have 300-500 columns. 
Some of tables have columns with special characters like .(dot) and space in the column names.

Now I want to do sqoop import and create a hive table in HDFS in a single shot query like below as textfile

```
sqoop import --connect ${domain}:${port}/$(database) --username ${username} --password ${password} --table $(table) -m 1 --hive-import --hive-database ${hivedatabase} --hive-table $(table) --create-hive-table --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/${hivedatabase}.db/$(table)
```

After this the hive table is created but when I do select * query on the table it shows error as

This error output is a sample output.

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find field emp from [0:emp.id, 1:emp.name, 2:emp.salary, 3:emp.dno]
```

However when I do the import as parquet file the table is created and when I do select query the query gives me expected results. Even the .(dot) are replaced with _(underscore) automatically

Why is this happening?

Comment: try using Free form query and give all columns name you require
My guess is may be sqoop is parsing your .dot and space into separate fields

Comment: @Rijulsahu I have tried --query options as well it still failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the above is due to a limitation in Hive. In hive they have disabled creation of hive tables with dot/colon in the column names.

They have a Jira for this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10120

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have those special characters in the columns names, it doesn't happend in parquet because SQOOP is transforming the column names to valid java indetifiers (for instance, java doesn't allow spaces in the identifiers). a workound is us the character ` to select your columns 1 to 1

```
select
`.(dot)`
from yourtable.
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: Do you mean select emp.id as emp_id …. From table. If yes then It would be difficult for a table mith more than 50 columns to maually specifiy aliases for each column. I would like to do that dynamically

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ShowColumns could work? I haven't tried but if it give you only the names, it could help.